# How does the light and energy breakdown depend on wave frequency?

Tags: optics, electromagnetic-radiation, frequency

How does light and light energy "breakdown" (when light is reflected, some light will be transmited, absorbed, or reflected, just like energy associated with light) depend on wave frequency? I've looked up similar questions, but they only seem to explain why light frequency doesn't change during reflection, and not why and how does the wave frequency influences the reflection.

Comment: I googled "reflectance dependency on frequency" and was referred back to a Stack Exchange answer of 2013 by John Rennie. The last paragraph is what you need to follow up. I'd give a link to the answer if I knew how to do links.

Comment: thank you very much